# Python MySQL - mysqldb query with parameters and other placeholder

Tags: python, mysql, query-string

I am trying to use the following query where I do some date_format manipulation and I would like also to use some placeholder. Unfortunately the query fails since it does not try to replace the placeholder. The query is the following:

```
query_with_parameters =  """select ID, IP_src, IP_dst, sum(bytes) as Total_Bytes, count(*) as total_packets,\
 ( sum(bytes) / count(*) )  as Average, date_format(date, "%H") as Hour , date_format(date, "%d %m %Y")\
  as date from Packets where date BETWEEN %s and %s group by IP_src,\
   IP_dst, Hour, date order by IP_src, IP_dst, Hour, date;"""
```

and I am trying to use it through:

```
cursor.execute(query_with_parameters, ('2013-06-30 00:00:00' , '2013-06-30 23:59:59'))
```

I am using mysqldb as library and Python 2.7
The Exception that I get is:

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError("unsupported format character 'H' (0x48) at index 144",), <traceback object at 0x33447a0>)
```

Any Ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED

```
query_with_parameters =  """select ID, IP_src, IP_dst, sum(bytes) as Total_Bytes, count(*) as total_packets, ( sum(bytes) / count(*) )\
  as Average, date_format(date, "%%H") as Hour , date_format(date, "%%d %%m %%Y") as date_n from Packets\
   where date BETWEEN %s and %s group by IP_src, IP_dst, Hour,\
    date_n order by IP_src, IP_dst, Hour, date_n;"""
```

By simply adding % in front of the one for the mysql db got it fixed ;)

Hope it may be helpful for others :D